# Building linux-tools deb produces empty binary packages

Tags: kernel, deb, packaging, linux-headers, debuild

I'm trying to build the [`linux-tools-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-tools-generic) package on Ubuntu Impish (i.e. 21.10).

I am trying to follow the guides I can find (e.g. [this one](https://tribaal.io/rebuilding-ubuntu-packages.html)), so the workflow looks something like this:

Set up by enabling `deb-src` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then:

```
apt-get install devscripts pbuilder build-essentials
apt-get build-dep linux-tools-generic
```

Then I get the actual source package:

```
apt-get source linux-tools-generic
```

Now `cd` to it and try to build (without signing for now):

```
cd linux-meta-5.13.0.39.48
debuild -uc -us
```

This produces a bit of spew which looks like the contents of the `debian/rules` files, but it creates a lot of empty packages, and nothing useful:

```
...
W: linux-lowlatency-hwe-20.04-edge: empty-binary-package
W: linux-source: empty-binary-package
W: linux-tools-generic: empty-binary-package
W: linux-tools-generic-hwe-20.04: empty-binary-package
W: linux-tools-generic-hwe-20.04-edge: empty-binary-package
...
```

Weirdly, it's saying "20.04", though my deb-src lines definitely say "impish" in them. But there's no error and it returns `0`.

How do I get it to actually build the binary packages?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Impish, per the first line (though do also want to do this on focal)

Comment: Aww sorry missed that was looking for a number.